# omniauth call back initiated twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I am using oauth for greenhouse using the "[omniauth-greenhouse](https://github.com/grnhse/omniauth-greenhouse) gem. However after the authentication, i see the call back initiated twice with following messages

```
(greenhouse) Setup endpoint detected, running now.
(greenhouse) Request phase initiated.

Started GET "/auth/greenhouse" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-27 21:41:49 -0700
(greenhouse) Setup endpoint detected, running now.
(greenhouse) Callback phase initiated.
/Users/ViswaMani/futura-project-enterprise/script/rails: No such file or directory - 
(greenhouse) Callback phase initiated.
(greenhouse) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, <!DOCTYPE html>
```

The invalid_credentials is coming because of the second call.

I made a new sample app that uses the gem and same credentials and i am able to authorize end to end. i am not sure what the issue is in my main app.

There is no device.rb and i am only creating the oauth only once in my omniauth.rb as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :greenhouse, 'foo', 'bar',
       :scope => 'candidates.create candidates.view jobs.view',
       :provider_ignores_state => true,
       :setup => lambda { |env| env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_options][:site] =  'https://app.greenhouse.io' }
end
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I had kind of same problem, and the problem was I had defined the OmniAuth  provider twice. One in its own file, and in device, which I was testing a new implementation with.